# Assembler:Problem with initializing variable

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, emu8086

I try find maximum repetitive number.

I get error when try initalize variable:

```
unknown opcode byte: Fh
Not supported yet. Not 8086 instruction.
```

So that is my code:

```
#make_COM#
    ORG 100H
    ARRAY DB 5,2,7,12,8,2,8,3,5,2,3,2,13,2
    ARRAYcnt DW 13
    ARRAYmax DW 0
    MOV AH,0
    MOV CX,ARRAYcnt
    MOV BX,0
    MOV AL,0
    MOV DL,ARRAY[BX] 
    xor si,si  

    External:  
    push CX
    MOV AH,0
    MOV DL,ARRAY[BX]
    MOV CX,ARRAYcnt
    Internal:
    CMP DL,ARRAY[si]
    JE label1
    continiue:
    INC si
    LOOP Internal
    xor si,si
    CMP AH,AL
    JG label2:
    continiue1:
    pop CX 
    INC BX
    LOOP External  

    HLT

    label1:INC AH
           JMP continiue
    label2:MOV AL,AH
           push BX  
           MOV BX,ARRAY[BX]
           MOV ARRAYmax,BX
           pop BX
           JMP continiue1
```

After that is error:`ARRAYcnt DW 15`

I change DW to DB .

Also I have tried write 15 as 0Fh.No result.

Please help

Comment: What generates this error?  Please post your full code (or better, an [mcve]) and some more details as to how you assemble and run your code.  If you use some sort of emulator, please let us know what it is.

Comment: I write in emu8086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that code execution begins at location `100h`, but your program has data, not code there.  Thus the processor attempts to execute your data as code, causing the problems you observe.  To fix this, move your data out of the path of execution, e.g. to the end of the program.

Comment: What do you mean exactly "to the end of the program"?

Comment: @sasha Place the data somewhere after all your code.  If emu8086 supports this, use sections to place the data into the data section.

Comment: ALL I do is set ARRAYcnt to 17 and add some elements to array.Now it works.I do not know if it is good/normal.

Comment: sasha “It works” doesn't mean your code is correct.  Make sure to move your arrays out of the way of code execution.  The processor doesn't know what is code and what is data and won't skip over any data when executing your code.  You must move your code to where the processor doesn't attempt to execute it.

Comment: I made that way:
`JMP PNT
ARRAY DB 5,2,7,12,8,2,8,3,5,2,3,2,13,2,2,2,2
ARRAYcnt DW 14
ARRAYmax DW 0h
PNT:`